# Angular Material md-tabs inside bootstrap modal rendering issue

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-material

I'm using angular material tabs inside a bootstrap modal. When I open the modal for the first time, only the first label from the three tabs is visible. When I'm clicking on the area the other two tabs will appear. I'm guessing it has something to do with the Html rendering, but I can't find a way to fix it. Can someone suggest a solution?

By way, the reason I'm using bs-modal and not angular material dialog is because I need to work with two modals at the same time, which is not possible with angular material's dialogs.

This is my code:

```html
<div id="settings-popup" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content" ng-controller="SettingsController">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true"></button>
                <h2 class="buzz-blue">Setting</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <!--BEGIN  tabs--->
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
                            <!--BEGIN  general settings--->
                            <md-tab>
                                <md-tab-label>General</md-tab-label>
                                <md-tab-body>
                                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                                        <!--content-->
                                    </md-content>
                                </md-tab-body>
                            </md-tab>
                            <!--END  general settings--->
                            <!--BEGIN  commercial settings--->
                            <md-tab>
                                <md-tab-label>Commercials</md-tab-label>
                                <md-tab-body>
                                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                                        <!--content-->
                                    </md-content>
                                </md-tab-body>
                            </md-tab>
                            <!--END commercial settings--->
                            <!--BEGIN running text settings--->
                            <md-tab>
                                <md-tab-label>Text</md-tab-label>
                                <md-tab-body>
                                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                                        <!--content-->
                                    </md-content>
                                </md-tab-body>
                            </md-tab>
                            <!--END running text settings--->
                        </md-tabs>
                    </div>
                    <!--END  tabs--->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide your code, please

Comment: I have edited the question and added my code. Thank you.